# Where to store user profile id for multiple user profile in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

In my laravel project, I have 2 tables as users and profiles. One user can have multiple profile. The user is logged into their account using user table. Now the profiles are listed as a drop-down menu. Once a user switch a profile by selecting anyone from the drop-down, what's the good practice to store the user profile id?

I'm planning to store the user's choice in the session.

Comment: I also think the session would be the best place. You also able to save it in a cookie, but I believe the Session is the easiest way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save the profiles in session array.

```
$profiles = array('prof1','prof2','prof3', ...);
Session::put('userProfiles', $profiles);
```

To show your session in a blade you can use a foreach:

```
@foreach (Session::get('userProfiles') as $profile)
    {{$profile}}
@endforeach
```

Note: this was one mode, for sure you can use other for same thing.